# Extract some files from a huge zip file listed in a text file in Linux

Tags: command-line, files, zip

I need to extract only specific files listed in a `.txt` file from a huge `.zip` file.

I tried:

```
cat /HGC/list.txt | while read file ; 
do 
gunzip all_human_gene-specific_connectomes_122015.zip 
find . -name "$file" -exec cp{}  /HGC \; 
done
```

Comment: Note that you are trying to use _gunzip_ to unpack .zip files, which is not correct (you should use unzip instead).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a subset of files as follows:

```
cat files.txt|xargs unzip archive.zip
```

Where *files.txt* - is the list of files to extract (may also include wildcards, see `man unzip`).

If your filenames are known to contains spaces, modify the command as follows:

```
cat files.txt|xargs -d '\n' unzip archive.zip
```